# Convert a list of numbers in php

Tags: php, replace, preg-replace

i need to convert the text below in php

```
11557
00337
00619
...
```

to

```
1hour 15min 57seconds
3min 37seconds
6min 19seconds
...
```

it's possible?

regards.

Comment: It's usually a good idea to share your code and gain feedback from people.

Answer (score 1):

I got it using:

```
<?php

$string = '00213';
$dto = DateTime::createFromFormat('his', sprintf('%06s', $string));
echo $dto->format('H:i:s');
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for your request and its quite easy

```
$arr_time = array('11557', '00337', '00619');

$arr_str = array();
foreach ($arr_time as $time) {
    $str_time = '';
    $hr = substr($time, 1, 1);//Extract hour
    $min = substr($time, -4, 2);//Extract min
    $sec = substr($time, -2, 2);//Extract sec
    if(!empty($hr)){
        $str_time .= (int)$hr . 'hour ';
    }
    if(!empty($min)){
        $str_time .= (int)$min . 'min ';
    }
    if(!empty($sec)){
        $str_time .= (int)$sec . 'seconds ';
    }

    echo $str_time . '<br/>';
}
```

Output:

```
1hour 15min 57seconds
3min 37seconds
6min 19seconds
```